# Python Telegram Bot: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I'm new to python and trying to setup a telegram bot, but when I run `python main.py` I receives this error message:

```
python main.py
  File "main.py", line 110
    f"Update Address ({address_changes}/{config.wallet_changes})",
                                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Code attached:

```
    def update_wallet_address_button(message): 
    connection = get_connection() 
    with connection.cursor() as cursor: 
        sql = "SELECT address_change_status FROM users WHERE user_id = %s" 
        cursor.execute(sql, message.chat.id) 
        address_changes = cursor.fetchone()["address_change_status"] 
        markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup() 
        markup.add( 
            InlineKeyboardButton( 
               f"Update Address ({address_changes}/{config.wallet_changes})", 
                callback_data="edit_wallet_address", 
            ) 
        ) 
        return markup


@bot.message_handler(
    func=lambda message: message.chat.type == "private", commands=["start"]
)
```

I would appreciate any advice.

Comment: 1) why python 2.7 ? 2) before `markup.add` do `print(address_changes)` and `print(config.wallet_changes)` - what do you get?

Comment: If you are using Python 2.7 then that's your problem, f-strings were added in Python 3.6.